# How to create admin user for specific store in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have a multi-store website which runs over different domains. I have also a multi-admin user. Now I need to set them for specific stores.

Basically I need admin user who can access data of only of specific store depends upon the settings created by main admin user.

Help me to resolve this.

Comment: You can check below link, hope this helps !
[link](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-new-admin-user-magento-2.html)

Comment: I want users for specific stores.

Comment: I think Magento doesn't provide this functionality, For that you need to create the module or use the paid extension.

Comment: Basically it is not possible, you need some extension like this : https://amasty.com/advanced-permissions-for-magento-2.html

Comment: Hello @SukumarGorai,
Have you found anything regarding user for specific store-view, they can access, CMS  block, pages etc for specific store-view? I need same requirement.