# Magento 2.3 limit scope change in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, scope, scope-switcher

How can one limit the change of scope in Magento 2 admin https://nimb.ws/QVDXuL.

Like if a user is ABC then he can only view ABC store view and not default store settings in (dashboard and configuration page).

Because I am using a multi-store with websites and created different users for each store. So I don't want any user to see default configurations.

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226281/how-to-create-admin-user-for-specific-store-in-magento2

Comment: you didn't get my point. I don't wan't a user to be able to switch scope of websites or stores. https://nimb.ws/QVDXuL

Answer (score 0):

there are extensions called "Advanced permissions" who restrict admin access per website / store view or other parameters.

I am using Aitoc advanced permissions a while now: https://www.aitoc.com/magento-2-advanced-permissions.html

Its possible to give a single store view/website or also multiple ones to a specific user group.